# React Hotkeys cannot access updated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, hotkeys

I am using `GlobalHotKeys` provided by `react-hotkeys` library to trigger some event when specified keyboard shortcut is entered. But the handler function cannot get the updated value of the state. Following is the code I used.

code sandbox code is available here: [this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-nobel-7oybh?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import React from 'react'
import { GlobalHotKeys } from 'react-hotkeys'

function Playground() {

  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)

  const handleEvent = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log("Count Value now is: ", count)
  }, [])

  return (
    <GlobalHotKeys
      keyMap={{
        FOCUS_BARCODE: 'alt+a'
      }}
      handlers={{
        FOCUS_BARCODE: handleEvent
      }}>
      <div>
        <h1>Here is count value: {count}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => setCount((count) => count + 1)}> Increase Count</button>
      </div>
    </GlobalHotKeys>
  )
}

export default Playground
```

**What is happening now**

Any time I hit the `alt+a`, it console logs count as `0`. I clicked on `Increase count` button and increased the value of `count` and then hitting `alt+a` still gives the value of `count` to be `0`.

**What I need**

I want to print the updated value of `count` with the hotkey.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add allowchanges..

```
<GlobalHotKeys
      keyMap={{
        FOCUS_BARCODE: 'alt+a'
      }}
      handlers={{
        FOCUS_BARCODE: handleEvent
      }} 
     allowChanges={true}
  >
      <div>
        <h1>Here is count value: {count}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => setCount((count) => count + 1)}> Increase Count</button>
      </div>
    </GlobalHotKeys>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code example to work with the hotkey. You have to put your console log in a useEffect call as it is a side-effect.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { GlobalHotKeys } from "react-hotkeys";

function Playground() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const handleEvent = React.useCallback(() => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
  }, [setCount]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Count Value now is: ", count);
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <GlobalHotKeys
      keyMap={{
        FOCUS_BARCODE: "alt+a"
      }}
      handlers={{
        FOCUS_BARCODE: handleEvent
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <h1>Here is count value: {count}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => setCount((count) => count + 1)}>
          {" "}
          Increase Count
        </button>
      </div>
    </GlobalHotKeys>
  );
}

export default Playground;
```

Sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-newton-08vyv

useEffect - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: That didn't work either. Even not passing dependency array didn't work.

Comment: I've updated my response, please take a look at the code sandbox

Comment: That isn't working still because pressing `alt+a` increases the count. I just want to print the count value when pressing `alt+a` without increasing the value of count.

Comment: Please take a look at the updated sandbox, it works now.

Comment: Thanks @Moot, how would I go about accessing other state values inside the handler? I see that you're updating count using the version of setCount that accepts the old value. But say I had another piece of state called  'amount' and I wanted to update 'count' by 'amount', I have tried this and it uses the value of 'amount' on program load, if 'amount' then changes, those changes aren't reflected in the handler. Hope that made sense.

Comment: Solved my own problem, for anyone else needing to access multiple pieces of state inside the handler, add them to the dependendies list AND set the 'allowChanges' prop to True on the HotKey Component.